# Assigns keys to a function outside the class angular

Tags: angular, function

```
import {Injectable, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User, WebStorageStateStore} from 'oidc-client';


import {UserService} from '../../shared/services/user.service';
import {KnownAuthenticationTypes} from '../types/known-authentication-types';
import {Login} from '../types/login';
import {LoginDto} from '../types/login-dto';
import {LoginMap} from '../types/login-map';
import {ChangePassword} from '../../settings/types/change-password';
import {ChangePasswordDto} from '../../settings/types/change-password-dto';
import {ChangePasswordMap} from '../../settings/types/change-password-map';
import {ResetPasswordRequestDto} from '../types/reset-password-request-dto';
import {BaseDto} from '../../shared/types/base-dto';
import * as Oidc from 'oidc-client';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {KnownRoutePath, KnownEvent} from '../../shared/types/known-routes';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationSecureAuthService implements OnDestroy {
  private readonly loginReturnUrlKey: string = 'loginReturnUrlKey';
  private user: User = null;
  private manager: UserManager;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {
    Oidc.Log.logger = console;
    Oidc.Log.level = Oidc.Log.INFO;
    this.manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
    this.start();
    
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stop();
  }

  // Make a call to "login" to web API using id_token from SecureAuth
  loginWithIdToken(idToken: string): Observable<Login> {
    const url = `${environment.apiSecurityOrigin}/security/tokenlogin`;
    const body = {idToken: idToken};

    console.log('About to call web API to fetch user auth token and roles');
    return this.http.post<BaseDto<LoginDto>>(url, body)
      .map(baseDto => {
        console.log('Returned from calling web API to fetch user auth token and roles');
        const vm = LoginMap.toVm(this.extractLoginDto(baseDto.value));
        if (vm.authenticationType === KnownAuthenticationTypes.Authenticated) {
          this.userService.setCurrentUser(vm.authenticationToken, vm.user);
        } else {
          this.userService.clearCurrentUserAndToken();
        }
        return vm;
      })
      .catch(this.handleLoginError);
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }

  getClaims(): any {
    return this.user.profile;
  }

  getIdToken(): string {
    return this.user.id_token;
  }

  getLoginReturnUrl(): string {
    let returnUrl: string = sessionStorage.getItem(this.loginReturnUrlKey);
    if (!returnUrl) {
      // Default to workqueues if sessionStorage not set.
      returnUrl = '/workqueues';
    }

    return returnUrl;
  }

  setLoginReturnUrl(returnUrl: string): void {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.loginReturnUrlKey, returnUrl);
  }

  startAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    }, reason => console.log('Error in signinRedirectCallback(): ' + reason));
  }

  private extractLoginDto(body: any) {
    return new LoginDto(body.authenticationToken, body.authentication, body.user);
  }

  private handleLoginError(response: Response | any) {
    return Observable.throw(response);
  }

  private start(): void {
    window.addEventListener('storage', this.storageEventListener.bind(this));
  }

  private storageEventListener(event) {
    if (event.key === KnownEvent.LogoutEventName) {
      // The user logged out of another tab, so log out here.
      console.log('User logged out of another tab, so logging out now.');
      this.router.navigate([KnownRoutePath.Logout]);
    }
  }

  private stop(): void {
    window.removeEventListener('storage', this.storageEventListener.bind(this));
  }
  private getkeys(): any  {
    return this.http
      .get('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/discovery/v2.0/keys');
   
  }
}

// BSCI SecureAuth endpoint
// metadataUrl:'https://secureauth.bsci.com/secureauth159/.well-known/openid-configuration',

export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {

  let baseUrl = 'https://' + window.location.hostname;
  if (window.location.port && window.location.port !== '443') {
    baseUrl = baseUrl + ':' + window.location.port;
  }

  return {
    metadata: {
       issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{id}/v2.0',
       authorization_endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`,
       token_endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token`
    },
    signingKeys: [
      {
          "kty": "RSA",
          "use": "sig",
          "kid": "",
          "x5t": "",
          "n": "",
          "e": "",
          "x5c": [ "" ],
          "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{id}/v2.0"
        }],
    
    client_id: `${environment.secureAuthClientId}`,
    redirect_uri: `${baseUrl}/auth-callback`,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: baseUrl,
    response_type: 'id_token',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: false,
    automaticSilentRenew: false,
    checkSessionInterval: 1000000,
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({store: sessionStorage})
  };
}
```

To give the background I am not an angular developer and this is very old code developed in angular 2.0. In the getclientsettings() function which is defined outside the class I need to remove the hardcoded values from the signingkeys and assign the values to it from a url which will provide the same values. I have the httpget method(getkeys) inside the class but I don't know how to pass the values that I get from this http method to the getclientsettings() function

Comment: The environment is a good place fore dev/prod variables. You could also use DI to pass values to the constructor and then the function… it depends on how many times you use the function…

Comment: Usually this function is called when we start the application. Can you provide me any example or reference on using the DI

Comment: When would the parameters change? Do they change during the app lifetime?

Comment: no. they will not change

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is to add the variables to the `./src/environments/environment.ts` and `./src/environments/environment.prod.ts`.

Then you would simply use `import { environment } from '../environment';`

---

If you want to use DI:

1. Create `get-client-settings-options-token.ts` and inside have `export const GetClientSettingsOptionsToken = new InjectionToken('GetClientSettingsOptions')`.
2. In `app.module.ts` add to providers: `{ provide: GetClientSettingsOptionsToken, useValue: ... }`.
3. In the `AuthenticationSecureAuthService` in the constructor add: `options: GetClientSettingsOptionsToken` and pass options to the `getClientSettings` function